Have enabled Pollen and airquality APIs, while both share the same Key invoking pollen api call errors
Have enabled Pollen and airquality APIs, while both share the same Key invoking pollen api  errors           The requested URL
AirQuality -- SUccess
https://airquality.googleapis.com/v1/currentConditions:lookup?key=myKey
Body
{
"location": {
"latitude": 37.419734,
"longitude": -122.0827784
}
}
Pollen API -- ERRORS
https://pollen.googleapis.com/v1/forecast:lookup?key=MYKEY&location.longitude=35.32&location.latitude=32.32&days=1
That’s an error.
The requested URL
    /v1/forecast:lookup?key=MYKEY&location.longitude=35.32&location.latitude=32.32&days=1
    was not found on this server. That’s all we know.
I tried various options keys etc but no luck
